# Is there a tutorial on how to implement non-consumable in app purchase in flutter?

Tags: flutter, in-app-purchase

I've been searching around the net but still no luck. I can't find a decent tutorial on non-consumable in app purchase in flutter, it's always about consumable. Does anybody know a tutorial in it? Please kindly share if you know any links or tutorials.